# ReastEasy Http Header for Client Request

Tags: java, rest, jboss, resteasy, rest-client

I'm accessing a rest web service using RestEasy ClienTRequest API. How can I set http header for the client request.

I need to add the following name value pair as http header.

```
username   raj
password   raj
```

This is the client code

```
public void getResponse(String uri, Defect defect)   {

         StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
         try{
         JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Defect.class);
         Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
         jaxbMarshaller.marshal(defect, writer);
         }catch( JAXBException e){

         }

        //Define the API URI where API will be accessed
        ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest("https://dev.in/rest/service/create");

        //Set the accept header to tell the accepted response format
        request.body("application/xml", writer.getBuffer().toString());
       // request.header("raj", "raj");
        //Send the request
        ClientResponse response;
        try {
            response = request.post();
             int apiResponseCode = response.getResponseStatus().getStatusCode();
             if(response.getResponseStatus().getStatusCode() != 201)
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed with HTTP error code : " + apiResponseCode);
                }
             System.out.println("response "+response.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //First validate the api status code




    }
```

Thanks in advance

Tried this coxe. but not working

```
Map<String, String> headerParam = new HashMap<String, String>(); headerParam.put("username", "raj"); headerParam.put("password", "raj"); request.header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, headerParam);
```

Comment: Map<String, String> headerParam = new HashMap<String, String>();
     headerParam.put("username", "raj");
     headerParam.put("password", "raj");
  request.header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, headerParam);

Comment: ClientRequest is deprecated. You may want to use the [jaxrs-2.0 Client API](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-3/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html), and just do something like `client.target(url).request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).header(...).header(...).get(..);`. Take a look at the [`Invocation.Builder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html) class for a few examples

Comment: @peeskillet: Do u have any sample code?

Comment: Those links 1. Invocation.Builder 2. jaxrs-2.0 Client API both have example code. Have you looked at them and tried?

Comment: I had tried, bot requires ClientBuilder(external jar).. Im using Jboss6.2 eap, Is there any client supported by this, not using any external jars

Comment: @peeskillet :javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar this jar, but not working.. Can you suggest which one to use

Comment: Try and use [this ones](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-client/3.0.9.Final) along with [this one](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/jaxrs-api/3.0.9.Final). You _are_ using maven right?

Comment: [resteasy-client](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-client) is the only main dependency you'll need to get it working. Keep in mind though, that jar depends on other jars also. So you'll want maven to automatically pull them in for you. This jar alone will not work by itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62110/discussion-between-rosh-and-peeskillet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple http client. Try following code. Make sure you handle exceptions properly.

```
        URL url = new URL("https://dev.in/rest/service/create");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;ver=1.0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("username", "raj");
        conn.setRequestProperty("password", "raj");

        String input = "{}" ; //set you json payload here.          
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());

        os.flush();        
        conn.disconnect();
```

You can find good examples with explanation [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/).